# Commas in formatting: y-values

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

When I compile the following code with the whole Tex document, it prints comma. On the other hand, if I compile it in a new single document, it prints the periods.

Do you know what may be causing this?

[image]

main.tex:

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}




\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}



\begin{document}


%
% Frontmatter
    \frontmatter
%   Titlepage
    \maketitle
%   Dedication
    \input{dedication}

    \input{summary}

%   Contents table
    \input{contents}

    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
% Mainmatter
    \mainmatter

    \pagestyle{plain}
    \input{intro}
    \input{chapter1}



    \appendix

% Backmatter
    \backmatter

    \bibliographystyle{apalike}
    \input{blibliography}


\end{document}
```

The code:

```
    \begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{subfigure}{.6\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ line width=1,/pgf/number format/.cd,
    use period,
       grid=major, % Display a grid
       tick label style={font=\bfseries\large},
       label style={font=\bfseries\Large},
    grid style={gray!30},
    xlabel={Epochs},
    ylabel={rmse}]
    \addplot[color=red,smooth] table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0] {
        1.1257
        0.992
        0.9681
        0.9579
        0.9521
        0.9485
        0.9457
        0.9445
        0.9432
        0.9424
        0.9413
        0.9409
        0.9409
        0.9408
        0.9402
        0.9397
        0.94
        0.9397
        0.9397
        0.9392
        0.9397
        0.9395
        0.9393
        0.9398
        0.9389
        0.9394
        0.9393
        0.9396
        0.9394
        0.9393
        0.9392
        0.939
        0.9389
        0.9394
        0.9393
        0.9385
        0.939
        0.9393
        0.9392
        0.9395
        0.9392
        0.9396
        0.9394
        0.9391
        0.9397
        0.9393
        0.9391
        0.9397
        0.9392
        0.9393
    };
    \addlegendentry{Validation Error} 
    \addplot[color=blue,smooth] table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0] {
        1.1257
        0.9836
        0.9558
        0.9431
        0.9359
        0.931
        0.9277
        0.9252
        0.9233
        0.9219
        0.9205
        0.9197
        0.9189
        0.9182
        0.9177
        0.9172
        0.9168
        0.9165
        0.9162
        0.9159
        0.9157
        0.9155
        0.9153
        0.9152
        0.915
        0.9149
        0.9147
        0.9146
        0.9145
        0.9143
        0.9143
        0.9142
        0.9141
        0.914
        0.914
        0.914
        0.9139
        0.9138
        0.9137
        0.9137
        0.9136
        0.9136
        0.9136
        0.9136
        0.9135
        0.9134
        0.9134
        0.9134
        0.9133
        0.9132
    };
    \addlegendentry{Train Error} 
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{RMSE  Movielens 100K}
    \label{fig:sub11}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering


    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[line width=1, 
    grid=major, % Display a grid
    grid style={gray!30},
     tick label style={font=\bfseries\large},
    label style={font=\bfseries\Large}, 
    xlabel={\textbf{Epochs}},
    ylabel={\textbf{rmse}}]
    \addplot[color=red,smooth] table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0] {
        1.1171
        0.9495
        0.9254
        0.9157
        0.9105
        0.9073
        0.9052
        0.9037
        0.9026
        0.9019
        0.9012
        0.9008
        0.9005
        0.9
        0.8997
        0.8996
        0.8994
        0.8991
        0.899
        0.8989
        0.8988
        0.8988
        0.8987
        0.8987
        0.8985
        0.8985
        0.8984
        0.8984
        0.8983
        0.8983
        0.8983
        0.8983
        0.8982
        0.8982
        0.8981
        0.8982
        0.8981
        0.8981
        0.8981
        0.8981
        0.8981
        0.898
        0.898
        0.898
        0.898
        0.898
        0.898
        0.898
        0.898
        0.8981
    };
    \addlegendentry{Validation Error} 
    \addplot[color=blue,smooth] table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0] {
        1.1171
        0.953
        0.9303
        0.9217
        0.9171
        0.9144
        0.9126
        0.9114
        0.9105
        0.91
        0.9095
        0.9092
        0.9091
        0.9088
        0.9085
        0.9085
        0.9084
        0.9082
        0.9081
        0.9081
        0.9081
        0.9081
        0.9081
        0.908
        0.9079
        0.9079
        0.9079
        0.908
        0.9079
        0.9078
        0.908
        0.9079
        0.9078
        0.9078
        0.9078
        0.9079
        0.9079
        0.9078
        0.9079
        0.9079
        0.9078
        0.9079
        0.9078
        0.9080
        0.9079
        0.9078
        0.9079
        0.9079
        0.9079
        0.9080
    };
    \addlegendentry{Train Error} 
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{RMSE  Movielens 1M}
    \label{fig:sub22}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{.}
\label{}


\end{figure}
```

Packages I am using:

```
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                  
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                    
 \usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}         
 \usepackage{graphicx}                       
 \usepackage{amsthm, amsmath, amssymb}      
\usepackage{setspace}\onehalfspacing        
\usepackage[loose,nice]{units}             
\usepackage{DF-MSc-titlepage}               
\usepackage{indentfirst}                   
\usepackage{lipsum}                         
\usepackage{aas_macros}                     
\usepackage{hyperref}                       
\usepackage{bookmark}                        
\usepackage{fancyhdr}        


\usepackage{emptypage}                    
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}           
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
%{m\usetikzlibraryatrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
%% Change to another style
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\MatrixVariable}[1]{\bm{\mathit{#1}}}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcommand\myeq{\mathrel{\overset{\makebox[0pt]{\mbox{\normalfont\tiny\sffamily def}}}{=}}}
%\usepackage{minted}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,      
    urlcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue
}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mwe}




\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{epsfig}


%\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
%\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[spanish,ruled]{algorithm2e}

\usepackage{contour}
\contourlength{1pt}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage{array}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newcommand*{\defeq}{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}        
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}
%\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,arrows.meta}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\newcommand\myeq{\mathrel{\stackrel{\makebox[0pt]{\mbox{\normalfont\tiny def}}}{=}}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\smartdiagramset{border color=none,uniform color list=blue for all items}
%\usepackage{enumitem}
\usetikzlibrary{%
    arrows,%
    calc,%
    arrows.meta,
    fit,%
    patterns,%
    plotmarks,%
    shadows,
    shapes.geometric,%
    shapes.misc,%
    shapes.symbols,%
    shapes.arrows,%
    shapes.callouts,%
    shapes.multipart,%
    shapes.gates.logic.US,%
    shapes.gates.logic.IEC,%
    er,%
    automata,%
    backgrounds,%
    chains,%
    topaths,%
    trees,%
    petri,%
    mindmap,%
    matrix,%
    % calendar,%
    folding,%
    fadings,%
    through,%
    positioning,%
    scopes,%
    decorations.fractals,%
    decorations.shapes,%
    decorations.text,%
    decorations.pathmorphing,%
    decorations.pathreplacing,%
    decorations.footprints,%
    decorations.markings,%
    shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending,positioning,calc}
\pgfkeyssetvalue{/cfr/soul base dimension}{5pt}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

%\usepackage[spanish,linesnumbered,inoutnumbered ,ruled]{algorithm2e} %for psuedo code

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}

\lstset{style=mystyle}



\graphicspath{{./figures/}}                 
%\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}                 
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}         

\geometry{bindingoffset=1cm}                
\geometry{textwidth=390pt}
```

Some macros I am using, also(sty):

```
%
%  These Macros are taken from the AAS TeX macro package version 5.2
%  and are compatible with the macros in the A&A document class
%  version 7.0
%  Include this file in your LaTeX source only if you are not using
%  the AAS TeX macro package or the A&A document class and need to
%  resolve the macro definitions in the TeX/BibTeX entries returned by
%  the ADS abstract service.
%
%  If you plan not to use this file to resolve the journal macros
%  rather than the whole AAS TeX macro package, you should save the
%  file as ``aas_macros.sty'' and then include it in your LaTeX paper
%  by using a construct such as:
%   \documentstyle[11pt,aas_macros]{article}
%
%  For more information on the AASTeX and A&A packages, please see:
%       http://journals.aas.org/authors/aastex.html 
%       ftp://ftp.edpsciences.org/pub/aa/readme.html
%  For more information about ADS abstract server, please see:
%       http://adsabs.harvard.edu/ads_abstracts.html
%

% Abbreviations for journals.  The object here is to provide authors
% with convenient shorthands for the most "popular" (often-cited)
% journals; the author can use these markup tags without being concerned
% about the exact form of the journal abbreviation, or its formatting.
% It is up to the keeper of the macros to make sure the macros expand
% to the proper text.  If macro package writers agree to all use the
% same TeX command name, authors only have to remember one thing, and
% the style file will take care of editorial preferences.  This also
% applies when a single journal decides to revamp its abbreviating
% scheme, as happened with the ApJ (Abt 1991).

\let\jnl@style=\rm
\def\ref@jnl#1{{\jnl@style#1}}

\def\aj{\ref@jnl{AJ}}                   % Astronomical Journal
\def\actaa{\ref@jnl{Acta Astron.}}      % Acta Astronomica
\def\araa{\ref@jnl{ARA\&A}}             % Annual Review of Astron and Astrophys
\def\apj{\ref@jnl{ApJ}}                 % Astrophysical Journal
\def\apjl{\ref@jnl{ApJ}}                % Astrophysical Journal, Letters
\def\apjs{\ref@jnl{ApJS}}               % Astrophysical Journal, Supplement
\def\ao{\ref@jnl{Appl.~Opt.}}           % Applied Optics
\def\apss{\ref@jnl{Ap\&SS}}             % Astrophysics and Space Science
\def\aap{\ref@jnl{A\&A}}                % Astronomy and Astrophysics
\def\aapr{\ref@jnl{A\&A~Rev.}}          % Astronomy and Astrophysics Reviews
\def\aaps{\ref@jnl{A\&AS}}              % Astronomy and Astrophysics, Supplement
\def\azh{\ref@jnl{AZh}}                 % Astronomicheskii Zhurnal
\def\baas{\ref@jnl{BAAS}}               % Bulletin of the AAS
\def\bac{\ref@jnl{Bull. astr. Inst. Czechosl.}}
                % Bulletin of the Astronomical Institutes of Czechoslovakia 
\def\caa{\ref@jnl{Chinese Astron. Astrophys.}}
                % Chinese Astronomy and Astrophysics
\def\cjaa{\ref@jnl{Chinese J. Astron. Astrophys.}}
                % Chinese Journal of Astronomy and Astrophysics
\def\icarus{\ref@jnl{Icarus}}           % Icarus
\def\jcap{\ref@jnl{J. Cosmology Astropart. Phys.}}
                % Journal of Cosmology and Astroparticle Physics
\def\jrasc{\ref@jnl{JRASC}}             % Journal of the RAS of Canada
\def\memras{\ref@jnl{MmRAS}}            % Memoirs of the RAS
\def\mnras{\ref@jnl{MNRAS}}             % Monthly Notices of the RAS
\def\na{\ref@jnl{New A}}                % New Astronomy
\def\nar{\ref@jnl{New A Rev.}}          % New Astronomy Review
\def\pra{\ref@jnl{Phys.~Rev.~A}}        % Physical Review A: General Physics
\def\prb{\ref@jnl{Phys.~Rev.~B}}        % Physical Review B: Solid State
\def\prc{\ref@jnl{Phys.~Rev.~C}}        % Physical Review C
\def\prd{\ref@jnl{Phys.~Rev.~D}}        % Physical Review D
\def\pre{\ref@jnl{Phys.~Rev.~E}}        % Physical Review E
\def\prl{\ref@jnl{Phys.~Rev.~Lett.}}    % Physical Review Letters
\def\pasa{\ref@jnl{PASA}}               % Publications of the Astron. Soc. of Australia
\def\pasp{\ref@jnl{PASP}}               % Publications of the ASP
\def\pasj{\ref@jnl{PASJ}}               % Publications of the ASJ
\def\rmxaa{\ref@jnl{Rev. Mexicana Astron. Astrofis.}}%
                % Revista Mexicana de Astronomia y Astrofisica
\def\qjras{\ref@jnl{QJRAS}}             % Quarterly Journal of the RAS
\def\skytel{\ref@jnl{S\&T}}             % Sky and Telescope
\def\solphys{\ref@jnl{Sol.~Phys.}}      % Solar Physics
\def\sovast{\ref@jnl{Soviet~Ast.}}      % Soviet Astronomy
\def\ssr{\ref@jnl{Space~Sci.~Rev.}}     % Space Science Reviews
\def\zap{\ref@jnl{ZAp}}                 % Zeitschrift fuer Astrophysik
\def\nat{\ref@jnl{Nature}}              % Nature
\def\iaucirc{\ref@jnl{IAU~Circ.}}       % IAU Cirulars
\def\aplett{\ref@jnl{Astrophys.~Lett.}} % Astrophysics Letters
\def\apspr{\ref@jnl{Astrophys.~Space~Phys.~Res.}}
                % Astrophysics Space Physics Research
\def\bain{\ref@jnl{Bull.~Astron.~Inst.~Netherlands}} 
                % Bulletin Astronomical Institute of the Netherlands
\def\fcp{\ref@jnl{Fund.~Cosmic~Phys.}}  % Fundamental Cosmic Physics
\def\gca{\ref@jnl{Geochim.~Cosmochim.~Acta}}   % Geochimica Cosmochimica Acta
\def\grl{\ref@jnl{Geophys.~Res.~Lett.}} % Geophysics Research Letters
\def\jcp{\ref@jnl{J.~Chem.~Phys.}}      % Journal of Chemical Physics
\def\jgr{\ref@jnl{J.~Geophys.~Res.}}    % Journal of Geophysics Research
\def\jqsrt{\ref@jnl{J.~Quant.~Spec.~Radiat.~Transf.}}
                % Journal of Quantitiative Spectroscopy and Radiative Transfer
\def\memsai{\ref@jnl{Mem.~Soc.~Astron.~Italiana}}
                % Mem. Societa Astronomica Italiana
\def\nphysa{\ref@jnl{Nucl.~Phys.~A}}   % Nuclear Physics A
\def\physrep{\ref@jnl{Phys.~Rep.}}   % Physics Reports
\def\physscr{\ref@jnl{Phys.~Scr}}   % Physica Scripta
\def\planss{\ref@jnl{Planet.~Space~Sci.}}   % Planetary Space Science
\def\procspie{\ref@jnl{Proc.~SPIE}}   % Proceedings of the SPIE

\let\astap=\aap
\let\apjlett=\apjl
\let\apjsupp=\apjs
\let\applopt=\ao
```

Comment: Unlike any other programming languages, it makes a lot of difference if you change the preamble of your document in terms of the output, such as clashing packages or page settings changed by some detail in the code and so on. That's why we need to have a complete example together with the relevant parts of your preamble included. Otherwise we might not be able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I will list the packages I am using, right now

Comment: @StefanPinnow I just posted everything I have! I still cannot make it work :(

Comment: The `\usepackage{babel}\usetikzlibrary{babel}` pair might be responsible, you could try to remove that. In general you should not load packages more than once, so this occurence of `\usepackage{babel}` should be removed anyway because you have `\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}` at the start of your document. You could try another language to see if it changes. Another candidate is `siunitx`. Remove also other duplicate packages, such as `mathtools` which is loaded multiple times. In general you should try to avoid loading packages that you don't actually use, such as `mwe` or

Comment: `filecontents`. This helps you to keep the document manageable. To find the actual source of the problem the strategy is to remove all content from your file except for the graph, compile it and check if the problem still occurs, then remove `\usepackage` statements one by one, compiling each time, until the problem disappears - the package that you removed last is (at least a part of) the problem.

Comment: I tried everything you mentioned but still, it does not work. I will try to find and apply a command like `\decimalpoint` to the whole document. Maybe that could work.

Comment: As was already mentioned in the comments, please make your code a **minimal** example, thus, remove all `\usepackage`s that don't changes the problem.

Comment: @StefanPinnow 

I was able to fix it! I added `\decimalpoint` and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As remark to your question and answer:

- Please always provide MWE (Minimal WorkingExample), a small but complete document, which reproduce your problem, in your case it can be as follows:

  ```
  \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
  \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
  \usepackage{pgfplots}
  \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

  \begin{document}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[line width=1,/pgf/number format/.cd, use period,
         grid=major, % Display a grid
         tick label style={font=\bfseries\large},
         label style={font=\bfseries\Large},
          grid style={gray!30},
          xlabel={Epochs},
          ylabel={rmse}]
      \addplot[color=red,smooth] table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0] {
          1.1257
          0.992
          0.9681
          0.9579
          0.9521
          0.9485
          0.9457
          0.9445
          0.9432
          0.9424
          0.9413
          0.9409
          0.9409
          0.9408
          0.9402
          0.9397
          0.94
          0.9397
          0.9397
          0.9392
          0.9397
          0.9395
          0.9393
          0.9398
          0.9389
          0.9394
          0.9393
          0.9396
          0.9394
          0.9393
          0.9392
          0.939
          0.9389
          0.9394
          0.9393
          0.9385
          0.939
          0.9393
          0.9392
          0.9395
          0.9392
          0.9396
          0.9394
          0.9391
          0.9397
          0.9393
          0.9391
          0.9397
          0.9392
          0.9393
      };
          \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
  ```

and gives:

[image]

- Also for solution is nice to add MWE, which enable testing of its works. For example:

  ... Issue is Spanish `babel`, which by default change decimal points to decimal commas. This can be changed on different ways. One of them is select different symbol with  `\spanishdecimal{<symbol>}`, for example by adding:

  ```
  \tikzset{
    every picture/.prefix style={
      execute at begin picture=\spanishdecimal{.}}    % <--- solve the problem
          }
  ```

  in document preamble. The complete MWE is:

  ```
  \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
  \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
  \usepackage{pgfplots}
  \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}  % not use `newest`, 
                             % you will lost information with which version MWE was tested

  \tikzset{
    every picture/.prefix style={
      execute at begin picture=\spanishdecimal{.}}    % <--- solve the problem
          }

  \begin{document}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[line width=1, % /pgf/number format/.cd, use period,
         grid=major, % Display a grid
         tick label style={font=\bfseries\large},
         label style={font=\bfseries\Large},
          grid style={gray!30},
          xlabel={Epochs},
          ylabel={rmse}]
      \addplot[color=red,smooth] table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0] {
          1.1257
          0.992
          0.9681
          0.9579
          0.9521
          0.9485
          0.9457
          0.9445
          0.9432
          0.9424
          0.9413
          0.9409
          0.9409
          0.9408
          0.9402
          0.9397
          0.94
          0.9397
          0.9397
          0.9392
          0.9397
          0.9395
          0.9393
          0.9398
          0.9389
          0.9394
          0.9393
          0.9396
          0.9394
          0.9393
          0.9392
          0.939
          0.9389
          0.9394
          0.9393
          0.9385
          0.939
          0.9393
          0.9392
          0.9395
          0.9392
          0.9396
          0.9394
          0.9391
          0.9397
          0.9393
          0.9391
          0.9397
          0.9392
          0.9393
      };
          \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}

  \end{document}
  ```

which gives:

[image]

- Do you really need all packages and libraries listed in your document preamble? If not, remove all not used. They only overwhelm document code and compilation process.
- The package `hypperref` should be loaded last except in rare excaption (for example before the `cleveref` package).

Comment: The screenshots both have commas, is that intentional?

Comment: @Marijn, no. That happens misprint  :-( .  corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it! I added `\decimalpoint` and it worked. By dafault, spanish changes to a comma as decimal separator; to change to a dot, I used \decimalpoint.
This gives the possibility to revert at any moment to a comma, using `\decimalcomma` or even to select a different symbol with `\spanishdecimal{<symbol>}`. I put the \decimalpoint command within the packages file.