# Resizing two subfigures inside a figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Hello folks and fellows!

I need to resize these two tikZ plots which are created when I run the whole tex document, so I don't think that  `\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{something.png}` would work. Do you know how I can fix this?

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, both plots are too big.

This is the code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{center}

    \begin{subfigure}{.6\textwidth}


        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[ line width=0.7,/pgf/number format/.cd,
        use period,
           grid=major, % Display a grid
           tick label style={font=\bfseries\large},
           label style={font=\bfseries\normalsize},
        grid style={gray!30},
        xlabel={Epochs},
        ylabel={rmse}]
        \addplot[color=red,smooth] table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0] {
            1.1257
            0.992
            0.9681
            0.9579
            0.9521
            0.9485
            0.9457
            0.9445
            0.9432
            0.9424
            0.9413
            0.9409
            0.9409
            0.9408
            0.9402
            0.9397
            0.94
            0.9397
            0.9397
            0.9392
            0.9397
            0.9395
            0.9393
            0.9398
            0.9389
            0.9394
            0.9393
            0.9396
            0.9394
            0.9393
            0.9392
            0.939
            0.9389
            0.9394
            0.9393
            0.9385
            0.939
            0.9393
            0.9392
            0.9395
            0.9392
            0.9396
            0.9394
            0.9391
            0.9397
            0.9393
            0.9391
            0.9397
            0.9392
            0.9393
        };


        \addlegendentry{Validation} 
        \addplot[color=blue,smooth] table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0] {
            1.1257
            0.9836
            0.9558
            0.9431
            0.9359
            0.931
            0.9277
            0.9252
            0.9233
            0.9219
            0.9205
            0.9197
            0.9189
            0.9182
            0.9177
            0.9172
            0.9168
            0.9165
            0.9162
            0.9159
            0.9157
            0.9155
            0.9153
            0.9152
            0.915
            0.9149
            0.9147
            0.9146
            0.9145
            0.9143
            0.9143
            0.9142
            0.9141
            0.914
            0.914
            0.914
            0.9139
            0.9138
            0.9137
            0.9137
            0.9136
            0.9136
            0.9136
            0.9136
            0.9135
            0.9134
            0.9134
            0.9134
            0.9133
            0.9132
        };
        \addlegendentry{Train} 
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{RMSE  Movielens 100K}
        \label{fig:sub11}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering

        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        line width=0.7, 
        grid=major, % Display a grid
        grid style={gray!30},
         tick label style={font=\bfseries\large},
        label style={font=\bfseries\normalsize},    
        xlabel={Epochs},
        ylabel={rmse}]
        \addplot[color=red,smooth] table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0] {
            1.1171
            0.953
            0.9303
            0.9217
            0.9171
            0.9144
            0.9126
            0.9114
            0.9105
            0.91
            0.9095
            0.9092
            0.9091
            0.9088
            0.9085
            0.9085
            0.9084
            0.9082
            0.9081
            0.9081
            0.9081
            0.9081
            0.9081
            0.908
            0.9079
            0.9079
            0.9079
            0.908
            0.9079
            0.9078
            0.908
            0.9079
            0.9078
            0.9078
            0.9078
            0.9079
            0.9079
            0.9078
            0.9079
            0.9079
            0.9078
            0.9079
            0.9078
            0.9080
            0.9079
            0.9078
            0.9079
            0.9079
            0.9079
            0.9080
        };
        \addlegendentry{Validation} 
        \addplot[color=blue,smooth] table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0] {
            1.1171
0.9495
0.9254
0.9157
0.9105
0.9073
0.9052
0.9037
0.9026
0.9019
0.9012
0.9008
0.9005
0.9
0.8997
0.8996
0.8994
0.8991
0.899
0.8989
0.8988
0.8988
0.8987
0.8987
0.8985
0.8985
0.8984
0.8984
0.8983
0.8983
0.8983
0.8983
0.8982
0.8982
0.8981
0.8982
0.8981
0.8981
0.8981
0.8981
0.8981
0.898
0.898
0.898
0.898
0.898
0.898
0.898
0.898
0.8981


        };
        \addlegendentry{Train} 
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{RMSE Movielens 1M}
        \label{fig:sub22}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Two datasets}


\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to define width of `subcaptions` environments and `pgfplots` images accordingly:

```
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[ width=\linewidth,
```

Considering my answer on your previous question ([Commas in formatting: y-values](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/491253/commas-in-formatting-y-values)), the MWE is:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}  % not use `newest`,
\tikzset{
  every picture/.prefix style={
    execute at begin picture=\spanishdecimal{.}}    % <--- solve the problem
        }

\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\pgfplotsset{width=\linewidth,
        grid=major, % Display a grid
        grid style={gray!30},
        tick label style={font=\small},
        label style={font=\bfseries},
        xlabel={Epochs},
        ylabel={rmse}
        }

    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        \addplot[color=red,smooth] table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0] {
            1.1257
            0.992
            0.9681
            0.9579
            0.9521
            0.9485
            0.9457
            0.9445
            0.9432
            0.9424
            0.9413
            0.9409
            0.9409
            0.9408
            0.9402
            0.9397
            0.94
            0.9397
            0.9397
            0.9392
            0.9397
            0.9395
            0.9393
            0.9398
            0.9389
            0.9394
            0.9393
            0.9396
            0.9394
            0.9393
            0.9392
            0.939
            0.9389
            0.9394
            0.9393
            0.9385
            0.939
            0.9393
            0.9392
            0.9395
            0.9392
            0.9396
            0.9394
            0.9391
            0.9397
            0.9393
            0.9391
            0.9397
            0.9392
            0.9393
        };

        \addlegendentry{Validation}
        \addplot[color=blue,smooth] table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0] {
            1.1257
            0.9836
            0.9558
            0.9431
            0.9359
            0.931
            0.9277
            0.9252
            0.9233
            0.9219
            0.9205
            0.9197
            0.9189
            0.9182
            0.9177
            0.9172
            0.9168
            0.9165
            0.9162
            0.9159
            0.9157
            0.9155
            0.9153
            0.9152
            0.915
            0.9149
            0.9147
            0.9146
            0.9145
            0.9143
            0.9143
            0.9142
            0.9141
            0.914
            0.914
            0.914
            0.9139
            0.9138
            0.9137
            0.9137
            0.9136
            0.9136
            0.9136
            0.9136
            0.9135
            0.9134
            0.9134
            0.9134
            0.9133
            0.9132
        };
        \addlegendentry{Train}
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{RMSE  Movielens 100K}
        \label{fig:sub11}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        \addplot[color=red,smooth] table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0] {
            1.1171
            0.953
            0.9303
            0.9217
            0.9171
            0.9144
            0.9126
            0.9114
            0.9105
            0.91
            0.9095
            0.9092
            0.9091
            0.9088
            0.9085
            0.9085
            0.9084
            0.9082
            0.9081
            0.9081
            0.9081
            0.9081
            0.9081
            0.908
            0.9079
            0.9079
            0.9079
            0.908
            0.9079
            0.9078
            0.908
            0.9079
            0.9078
            0.9078
            0.9078
            0.9079
            0.9079
            0.9078
            0.9079
            0.9079
            0.9078
            0.9079
            0.9078
            0.9080
            0.9079
            0.9078
            0.9079
            0.9079
            0.9079
            0.9080
        };
        \addlegendentry{Validation}
        \addplot[color=blue,smooth] table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0] {
            1.1171
0.9495
0.9254
0.9157
0.9105
0.9073
0.9052
0.9037
0.9026
0.9019
0.9012
0.9008
0.9005
0.9
0.8997
0.8996
0.8994
0.8991
0.899
0.8989
0.8988
0.8988
0.8987
0.8987
0.8985
0.8985
0.8984
0.8984
0.8983
0.8983
0.8983
0.8983
0.8982
0.8982
0.8981
0.8982
0.8981
0.8981
0.8981
0.8981
0.8981
0.898
0.898
0.898
0.898
0.898
0.898
0.898
0.898
0.8981


        };
        \addlegendentry{Train}
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{RMSE Movielens 1M}
        \label{fig:sub22}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Two datasets}


\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: you should considered my mentioned answer (regarding MWE) and all comments to your questions in all follows-up and also future question. Only code fragment of your problem require additional effort of people who are willing to help you. *Please, help us to help you and in future always provide MWE.*

**edit:** options from bot `axis` since that both are equal, I suggest to merge in common `pgfplotset` on begin of `figure`.

Comment: From now on, I won't be posting code fragments. Thank you for the remarks.