# Problems with figure size

Tags: floats, size

Hello fellows and folks!

Do you know why this is happening? All of the sudden, when I compiled the whole document, the matrix showed up like in the picture. I have this in every figure that appears in my document:

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
content
\end{figure}
```

And also this:

```
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering

    $ \underbrace{
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \checkmark & \color{blue}\textbf{?} & \checkmark & \color{blue}\textbf{?}  & \color{blue}\textbf{?}\\ 
    \color{blue}\textbf{?}&\color{blue}\textbf{?}  & \color{blue}\textbf{?} & \color{blue}\textbf{?} & \checkmark\\ 
    \checkmark& \color{blue}\textbf{?} & \checkmark & \checkmark & \color{blue}\textbf{?}\\ 
    \color{blue}\textbf{?}& \color{blue}\textbf{?} & \checkmark & \color{blue}\textbf{?}& \color{blue}\textbf{?}\\ 
    \color{blue}\textbf{?} &  \checkmark&  \color{blue}\textbf{?}& \checkmark & \color{blue}\textbf{?}\\ 
    \checkmark & \color{blue}\textbf{?} & \color{blue}\textbf{?} &\color{blue}\textbf{?} & \checkmark
    \end{bmatrix}
}_{\textbf{}}
    \neq
    \underbrace{ 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark\\ 
    \checkmark& \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark\\ 
    \checkmark& \checkmark &  \checkmark& \checkmark & \checkmark\\ 
    \checkmark&\checkmark  & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark\\ 
    \checkmark&\checkmark  & \checkmark & \checkmark & \color{blue}\textbf{?}\\ 
    \checkmark&  \checkmark& \checkmark & \checkmark & \color{blue}\textbf{?}
    \end{bmatrix}
}_{\textbf{}} 
    $

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is not the code you used to provide this image, `\checkmark` and `bmatrix` are not defined with this preamble. Please provide what is actually used to provide that image.

Comment: The preamble is a file full of packages...

Comment: What's the problem? The code is supposed to produce the image in the picture. If you are talking about the big interline space, then you probably have increased it with `setspace` or some other method.

Comment: The code you provide does not recreate the problem you mention, it cannot even be compiled, so how exactly are we suppose to help?

Comment: The problem is that everything seems larger in the document. I will add a picture before this happened. Instead of b matrix I used p matrix.

Comment: @daleif that's my teX document. [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/491253/commas-in-formatting-y-values]

Comment: I cannot copy and paste my 500 thesis TeX pages. I got that chunk of code and pasted it here. Maybe you knew what what was going on. I just pasted my preamble which is in the link I passed in the last comment.

Comment: And we can't debug code we can't compile. And I at least don't have the time and the will to wade through your various questions to find out how your document perhaps looks like and what could be the problem. You will have to learn to extract a minimal example from your code if you want sensible help. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/391022/2388

Comment: no one is asking you to paste a 500 page document, but you should make a small but complete _one page_ document that shows the problem. start from your thesis preamble and the above example, check it shows the problem, then delete everything you can while still showing the problem then post the resulting document.

Comment: I will do that. Thank you very much!

Comment: unrelated to the image that you show but `\begin{figure}[!htb]`  is a really bad option to use on every figure. Firstly it prevents float pages so makes it more than likely that every figure goes to the end of the document, secondly it uses `!` That is for _occasional_ use to over-ride document defaults, it clearly makes no sense to set document defaults then _always_ over-ride them, better to set the defaults that you want

Comment: Thank you, David! What would be the best choice, then? `h` alone?

Comment: no never use h alone. It is an _optional_ parameter so the best choice should be not to use it (and make the default float placement be what you want), but if you want to allow h without changing the default setting use `[htbp]`

Comment: Great. I’ll get rid of those immediately. Thank you!

Comment: For one thing, \checkmark from amsfonts is different from \checkmark from hyperref.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone} 
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
%%%>
\begin{comment}
:Title: A Venn diagram with PDF blending
:Tags: Diagrams;Cookbook
:Author: Stefan Kottwitz
:Slug: venn

PDF blend mode requires TikZ version 3.0 or above.
\end{comment}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[blend group = soft light]
    \fill[red!30!white]   ( 90:1.2) circle (2);
    \fill[green!30!white] (210:1.2) circle (2);
    \fill[blue!30!white]  (330:1.2) circle (2);
  \end{scope}
  \node at ( 90:2)    {Typography};
  \node at ( 210:2)   {Design};
  \node at ( 330:2)   {Coding};
  \node [font=\Large] {\LaTeX};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it. And I change the style of the check-mark.

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\blackcheck}{%
    \tikz\fill[scale=0.4, color=black]
    (0,.35) -- (.25,0) -- (1,.7) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle;%
}
```

What fixed the "problem" was this:

```
\begin{spacing}{0.5}
\end{spacing}
```

The code:

```
   \begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
  \begin{spacing}{0.5}


    $ \underbrace{
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \blackcheck & \color{blue}\textbf{?} & \blackcheck & \color{blue}\textbf{?}  & \color{blue}\textbf{?}\\ 
    \color{blue}\textbf{?}&\color{blue}\textbf{?}  & \color{blue}\textbf{?} & \color{blue}\textbf{?} & \blackcheck\\ 
    \blackcheck& \color{blue}\textbf{?} & \blackcheck & \blackcheck & \color{blue}\textbf{?}\\ 
    \color{blue}\textbf{?}& \color{blue}\textbf{?} & \blackcheck & \color{blue}\textbf{?}& \color{blue}\textbf{?}\\ 
    \color{blue}\textbf{?} &  \blackcheck&  \color{blue}\textbf{?}& \blackcheck & \color{blue}\textbf{?}\\ 
    \checkmark & \color{blue}\textbf{?} & \color{blue}\textbf{?} &\color{blue}\textbf{?} & \blackcheck
    \end{bmatrix}
}_{\text{Predicción de calificaciones}}
    \neq
    \underbrace{ 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \blackcheck & \blackcheck & \blackcheck & \blackcheck & \blackcheck\\ 
    \blackcheck& \blackcheck & \blackcheck & \blackcheck & \blackcheck\\ 
    \blackcheck& \blackcheck &  \blackcheck& \blackcheck & \blackcheck\\ 
    \blackcheck&\blackcheck  & \blackcheck & \blackcheck & \blackcheck\\ 
    \blackcheck&\blackcheck  & \blackcheck & \blackcheck & \color{blue}\textbf{?}\\ 
    \blackcheck&  \blackcheck& \blackcheck & \blackcheck & \color{blue}\textbf{?}
    \end{bmatrix}
}_{\text{Regresión o clasificación}} 
    $
\end{spacing}
```

[image]

Thank you all!